# Howto organize different project versions that require different Java versions? [Java1.5, Java6, Java8]

Tags: java, git, maven

Like Apache Lang or Apache Collections, older versions of my project require only Java1.5. But I would like to continue with that project and introduce also types that require Java8.

Importantly I don't want to change Java requirements for the complete project to Java8, since some legacy projects did not move to Java8 yet, so they need Java1.5 compatibility.

I need to frequently release new maintenance versions of the Java1.5-only project.

How do I do that?

1. create a new project repository [Java8 only] that depends on the old one [Java1.5]?
2. Somehow use the same repository and use different git HEADs? I think this is how Apache is doing it, but I could not find out why they did not just use a new repository? I can image it is much more effort to maintain all different build files and settings.

Comment: A target Java version should be confugurable via configuration files of a build system (Maven, Grable, Ant etc.). How to set it in Maven: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: Is there any reason you can't run it all in Java 8?

Comment: Why not use one git repository and just use different branches?

Comment: Yes, different branches is one way to do it. I was just wondering if this is the "right"/best way.

Comment: The best solution is to define the java via toolchains which gives you the opportunity to have each module a different java version...apart from that I would migrate those older projects (JDK 5, 6) to use for building JDK 8 cause JDK 5, 6 (7?) are out of support now...which means it is time to move on...